# How do I scale all the text in a ggplot by some multiple?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I make a ggplot chart, the font is typically too small for me to share it with others.

Sometimes I'll go in and make guesses about the right font size with layers like this:

```
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 30),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20))
```

I'd like to scale up all the text by some multiple, like make all the text elements 4 times bigger.

This is my code

```
  iris %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
              geom_point(size = 2, color = "purple") +
              labs(title = "Sepal Length by sepal width") +
              theme_ipsum_rc(grid = "XY",
                 base_size = 50)
```

I tried the solution in @Duck's answer, and it doesn't appear to affect the axis titles.

I'd like this solution to affect all the elements that are listed in the first code block!

Comment: While this doesn't exactly answer your question, I often set the `base_size` to something larger based on whatever overall theme I'm building on.  The default is 11 for, e.g., `theme_gray()` and `theme_bw()` and I often go up to something quite a bit larger like 14 or 16.

Comment: I wish the documentation was more verbose for the theme_set() arguments

Comment: I definitely found seeing what was in some of the complete themes more useful than the documentation for `theme_set()`; e.g., `?theme_gray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `theme_set()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Set theme
theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 18))
#Code
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, color = "purple") +
  labs(title = "Sepal Length by sepal width")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It also doesn't appear to affect the x-axis labels or the y-axis labels

Comment: @Cauder You can change again by using `theme_set()` again once a determined plot is created!

Comment: Something like this: theme_set(theme_bw())

Comment: @Cauder Just a moment. I will share with you other code!

Comment: Try this option to only change a specific plot: `iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, color = "purple") +
  labs(title = "Sepal Length by sepal width")+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20)) 
`